# Running one instance of a program per GPU-core on all GPU-cores simultaneously

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda, opencl, gpgpu

We have millions of small files to be processed by some programs.

The precise program <strike>is not important and</strike> varies <strike>also</strike> with the precise task. However, these are smaller C++-programs, and we have the source code, but they are not intrinsically parallelizable.

The processing of one small file takes around 15 seconds when using a single average CPU core (Intel i7 series). And it requires around 200 MB of RAM while the program is running.

We want to parallelize this on GPUs, and run on each GPU-core (e.g. Cuda-core) one instance of the program. Thus, if the GPU has 3000 CUDA-cores, then we would like to run 3000 instances in parallel. If possible we want to use a general framekwork like OpenCL (rather than Cuda, but if Cuda is needed for this case that will be acceptible).

Right now we are trying to assess if this will be possible (we don't have much experience yet with GPGPU programming). The main problem which we imagine is the memory. If we run for instance 3000 instances in parallel, and each instance would need 200 MB VRAM, then we would need 600 GB of memory.

The graphics cards which we have primarily in mind are high-end Geforce cards, which usually have between 8 GB and 11 GB of memory. And we have GPU workstations with 4 cards per case/mainboard, which we wan to use for that at first (but later maybe also on other GPU systems, therefore we prefer a general framework like OpenCL).

Which ways are there to solve this problem?

Comment: Won't memory bandwidth / latency be a bottleneck after just 3-5 instances? You would need a pseudo-malloc inside the kernel such that it returns only a "coalesced" group of addresses for all requesting threads(at that time) from an already cuda-malloced global buffer. Even this may not work if instances are not ordered in a manner to do less branching between themselves. Better way is to parallelise your algorithm run only enough instances to overlap data transfers, file reads and compute.

Comment: GPUs don't offer anything like the level of granularity you suggest you need, so no you can't do this.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik, thank you for your comment. I can't answer you question, but others might.

Comment: @talonmies: If you mean with granularity a mechanism which carries out the parallelization in the way we want, such a code we can write ourselves if there exists no module/package which can support us here. The question is, is it doable, i.e. is the memory problem solvable.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik: But I don't think there is a memory bottleneck after 3-5 instances, because one instance takes around 15 seconds on a CPU core to complete, meaning that it would take 300 seconds or more on a GPU core. So only 200 MB per 300 seconds roughly.

Comment: I mean that GPU cores are not fully independent processors which can run different code. Your "3000 core" consumer GPU has 20-30 processors. each with a lot of ALU cores. They can't all run different instructions simultaneously, they are functionally like SIMD units, grouped in 32 core groups. You can run something like 8 to 32 concurrent kernels at a time at an abolsute maximum

Comment: You can't run a complete program on a single GPU core.  The closest thing that fully supports one or more  threads of execution is the CUDA GPU SM, not core.

Comment: @talonmies: Thank you very much, we are coming the solution already closer :-) Since 32 parallel instances are no problem regarding memory. One question is now, if we run 32 concurrent kernels, does this mean that we have 100 % GPU utilization to get the maximum speedup, or do we need to optimize each kernel further to use each SIMD unit most efficiently?

Comment: @RobertCrovella: Many thanks for your comment. Does one SM corresponding one SIMD unit? If not, is it generally difficult to optimize the process which uses the SM most efficiently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The precise program is not important

This is wishful thinking. The problem you are trying to solve is *immensely* important; if it was as simple as recompiling C++ code to GPU shader binaries, pretty much all software would be doing that for a free speed boost.

You will not generally be able to convert an entire C++ program 1:1 into a GPU kernel, and even if you manage to do it, it will perform extremely badly. You really will need to go to the effort of rethinking your problem in terms of SIMD-type operations in order to get anywhere with GPUs.

In particular, you seem to be under the impression that each GPU "core" is independent. This is not the case, groups of them work in lock-step, so if your code is branch-heavy, you will have very poor utilisation. They also share the memory bus, so if each thread accesses uncorrelated memory regions, this will massively slow down execution, and you will not be able to feed the ALU/FPU fast enough.

Memory is also an issue, but not just because of the total amount of VRAM as you point out, but also because local variables use "private" memory, which are actually registers, and which are very much a limited resource (measured in kilobytes at best).

I recommend looking into the OpenCL optimisation guides published by all the major GPU vendors. This will give you a good idea of what kind of code performs well and what does not, and what considerations to make when deciding what code to offload to the GPU and how.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it was very helpful. I have corrected my question above according to your information (i.e. crossed out the statement that the program is not important). Regarding your statement "if it was as ... pretty much all software would be doing that for a free speed boost", maybe one should add here that all software which has large numbers of independent tasks to carry out could do that, but this is not the case for most software.

Comment: @Jadzia Many pieces of software can be adapted for GPU acceleration. However, the resulting code usually looks nothing like the original, and in many cases, the algorithms must be radically re-thought. So I'm not sure about your "most software" statement; perhaps most software in general, but probably not most software that is CPU-bound. (You haven't provided enough detail about what you're doing for me to say whether or not that applies to your software. Even some traditionally serial workloads such as compression can frequently benefit from GPU-acceleration when given enough thought.)